# Sending to a WebSocket server with PHP?

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, websocket

I'm running a Node.js WebSocket server on port 3000 on the same machine that I'm running Apache/PHP by running a reverse-proxy through Apache. This is my HTTPD file:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyRequests off
     SSLProxyEngine on
     ProxyPass /node/ ws://localhost:3000/node/
     ProxyPassReverse /node/ ws://localhost:3000/node/
  </VirtualHost>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
     ProxyRequests off
     SSLProxyEngine on
     ProxyPass /node/ ws://localhost:3000/node/
     ProxyPassReverse /node/ ws://localhost:3000/node/
  </VirtualHost>
```

Let's say my domain name is "example.com". Then, to connect to the WebSocket server through a browser, I would use this JS:

```
var connection = new WebSocket("wss://example.com/node/");
```

This works fine, and I'm successfully sending and receiving messages from browsers.

However, I also need to be able to send (not receive) messages to the WebSocket server using PHP, from the same machine. I've tried several configurations of fsockopen, and none of them have worked. Here are the ones I've tried, with the resulting error messages:

```
$fp = fsockopen("example.com/node/", 3000); //php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

$fp = fsockopen("ssl://example.com/node/", 3000); //php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

$fp = fsockopen("tls://example.com/node/", 3000); //php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

$fp = fsockopen("http://example.com/node/", 3000); //Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

$fp = fsockopen("https://example.com/node/", 3000); //Unable to find the socket transport "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

$fp = fsockopen("wss://example.com/node/", 3000); //Unable to find the socket transport "wss" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

$fp = fsockopen("ws://example.com/node/", 3000); //Unable to find the socket transport "ws" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

$fp = fsockopen("example.com/node/", 443); //php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

$fp = fsockopen("ssl://example.com/node/", 443); //php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

$fp = fsockopen("tls://example.com/node/", 443); //php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

$fp = fsockopen("http://example.com/node/", 443); //Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

$fp = fsockopen("https://example.com/node/", 443); //Unable to find the socket transport "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

$fp = fsockopen("wss://example.com/node/", 443); //Unable to find the socket transport "wss" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

$fp = fsockopen("ws://example.com/node/", 443); //Unable to find the socket transport "ws" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

$fp = fsockopen("example.com/node/", 80); //php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

$fp = fsockopen("ssl://example.com/node/", 80); //php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

$fp = fsockopen("tls://example.com/node/", 80); //php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

$fp = fsockopen("http://example.com/node/", 80); //Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

$fp = fsockopen("https://example.com/node/", 80); //Unable to find the socket transport "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

$fp = fsockopen("wss://example.com/node/", 80); //Unable to find the socket transport "wss" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

$fp = fsockopen("ws://example.com/node/", 80); //Unable to find the socket transport "ws" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

I've also tried all of those configurations using "localhost" and "127.0.0.1". And I've also experimented using the built-in PHP library functions socket_create and socket_connect, with all of those same hostnames, IP's, and ports - all resulting in the same types of "unknown host" errors. What am I doing wrong? What is the right way to do this?

Comment: WebSockets is an upgrade over HTTP/HTTPS,  so what about trying to use http or https as a parameter for your `fsockopen` function ??  Also, why do you want to do that? why not making a normal HTTP/HTTPS endpoint in your Node.JS server and call it from PHP via Guzzle or Curl ?

Comment: I just tried the http and https protocols, and they both resulted in the "unable to find socket transport" error.

Comment: Check out `php-websocket` https://github.com/nekudo/php-websocket

Comment: The php-websocket client class uses the same fsockopen function to connect... so I'll have the same problems as I'm having now.

Comment: Meaning this issue is not websocket specific, but rather you're addressing an incorrect host/port combination. Have you tried running a standard HTTP server on port 3000 and seeing if you can connect there? Also, if you know the Node server is on port 3000 what's the purpose in you trying all these other ports? Try `telnet 127.0.0.1 3000` and let us know perhaps what happens

Comment: [socket_create](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php) : / see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702855/php-websocket-connection-to-node-js-server